# Why my pyramid pattern code is not working?

Tags: c, for-loop, design-patterns

So I tried below code for pyramid pattern  and in output pattern first star is getting misplaced.can you tell me why this is happening?

[This code I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cbbZ.jpg)

[This is output i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BecyB.jpg)

[This is output i am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbaqX.jpg)

I tried to develope star pyramid but one star is not getting placed where it is expected in pattern as you can see in above image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code, sample input and expected output as text and not as images.

Comment: As noted, please include your code as text.  FYI, retyping the code you supplied in your image, I printed out the desired pyramid.  That leads me to believe there is a typo in your actual code as opposed to the supplied code in the image.  You might want to double check the statement "for (k=i; k<3; k++)" as your output image would seem to indicate that that "for" loop is not executing.  Also, check your compiler output for any warnings.

Comment: Do _not_ post _images_ of code/text or _links_. Images are often chopped. They frequently leave out necessary information. They can't be downloaded/examined. Put code/text in code block(s) here _To create a code block:_ In your editor, select the [desired] text. Copy to clipboard [with `ctrl-c`]. Edit the _question_ here [using the `edit` button]. Scroll to bottom. Enter `\`\`\`` on a separate line [to start a code block]. Then `ctrl-v` to paste in the text. Then, another `\`\`\`` line [to end the code block]. Then, click on the save button.

Comment: Please follow Craig Estey's instructions.  You can easily salvage this question by removing the pictures and replacing them with real text.  Make sure it's 100% accurate for what you're actually running

Comment: I will keep in mind and write code insted of posting image.It is my first question so  in future I will try  to improve.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran the code in the picture on my own computer, it gave the expected output. The only thing I can think of is your output gets clipped in whatever the online compiler is doing.

If you are learning C, I would really recommend you run the compiler on your own computer, an online tool will only get you so far so you will have to learn how to anyway.

Comment: Thank You ! When I ran this code on other compiler it worked.

Comment: Also can you tell me why in online compiler output gets clipped ?

Comment: My guess is when they store the output, somewhere in the pipeline they're using a trim() function. Why would they be doing that? I have no idea...